# Bootstrap: How to fix panel height and make an image inside of the panel follow that fixed height?

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

I'm putting an image inside bootstrap's panel but no matter what I do, the panel's height always adjust to the image's height. How do I make a fixed panel height and how do I make the image's height adjust to the panel's fixed height?

Answer (score 0):

If your panel already has a fixed height and your image is inside the panels div, just add a style of:

```
height: 100%;
```

to your image.

Example:

```
<div class="test">
<img src="test.jpg">
</div>
```

And your css:

```
.test {
  background-color: red;
  height: 50px;
}

.test img {
  height:100%;
}
```